# guard node unexpected change, is it expected behavior?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, guard-node

my guard node is changing between two countries in different sites is it normal ?

also, when i open tor my guard node is always the same, but some time passed it changes to another country but if i restart tor all goes back to normal.
here's the video showing the guard node changing:
https://streamable.com/e28q8s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK: it can be a normal GeoIP jitter, tor network backup circuits or integration leve upgrade for your tor instance. For the best experience make sure you have your `ORPort` reachable from outside and a setting for `ClientOnly` mode is 0 as it is by default. It will **not** make you an exit node, but an intermediate one **and** will improve your tor network membership greatly

Comment: i would edit my question just now, i finally was able to reproduce this. Here's the video that shows the tor guard changing: https://streamable.com/e28q8s. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: just a tip: use a *paid* GeoIP database, it's worth it for privacy - it's a way more accurate. the conversion tools are available with Tor source code